# Pandas - groupby cumulative timeperiod

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my problem:
Imagine a dataframe indexed by time.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["00:00:00", 
"00:00:08","00:00:14","00:00:21","00:00:23","00:00:49"],data={"col1":["a", 
"b","a","a", "c", "d"], "col2":[4,4,4,6,6,7], "col3":[2,17,2,2,3,50]})
```

I would now like to apply a function and group the data based on cumulative time in 15 second intervals, i.e. for timestamps between 00:00:00 - 00:00:15, 00:00:00 - 00:00:30, 00:00:00 - 00:00:45, etc.

Let's say for example, I want to sum all values of col2, col3 and divide one by the other, if the value in col1 is "a" in each of those intervals.

The output should be something like:

```
         output
00:00:15    2
00:00:30    2.3333
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It looks like you need resample() function, instead of groupby().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert index to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add `15 seconds` for shifting it, then filter only `a` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`).

Then [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) `sum`, then [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and last divide columns by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index) + pd.Timedelta(15, unit='s')

df = df[df['col1'].eq('a')].resample('15S').sum().cumsum()
df['out'] = df['col2'].div(df['col3'])
print (df)
          col2  col3       out
00:00:15     8     4  2.000000
00:00:30    14     6  2.333333
```

Alternative is converting to `datetime`s:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) + pd.Timedelta(15, unit='s')

df = df[df['col1'].eq('a')].resample('15S').sum().cumsum()
df['out'] = df['col2'].div(df['col3'])
print (df)
                     col2  col3       out
2019-03-21 00:00:15     8     4  2.000000
2019-03-21 00:00:30    14     6  2.333333
```

Comment: Apologies, I had an error in the output. This will give me the sum for the individual 15S "buckets", but rather I want a cumulative sum, always starting from 00:00:00 to the next 15s time interval.

Comment: @SanMu - Can you explain `2.3333` value? How is counted?

Comment: so for all "a" in col1, divide the sum of corresponding values in  col2 by the sum of corresponding values in col3 between 00:00:00 and 00:00:30 (i.e. 14/6=2.3333). Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["00:00:00", "00:00:08","00:00:14","00:00:21","00:00:23","00:00:49"],data={"col1":["a","b","a","a", "c", "d"], "col2":[4,4,4,6,6,7], "col3":[2,17,2,2,3,50]})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%H:%M:%S')
df = df[df['col1']=='a'].resample('15s', how='sum').cumsum()
df['output'] = df['col2']/df['col3']
```

Comment: Apologies, I had an error in the output. This will give me the sum for the individual 15S "buckets", but rather I want a cumulative sum, always starting from 00:00:00 to the next 15s time interval.

Comment: Then just add .cumsum() after .resample(), just like jezrael did